# How to open a beverage can that has a broken tab?

Tags: substitute-tool, drinks

I believe using force is not an option as it contains carbonated beverage.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use an actual can opener to open your can. Either place the flat rectangular end of the can opener against the normal opening of the can and pry it open, or place the pointy end of the can opener against **another** part of the lid and pry a new hole in the lid to drink out of.

[image: can opener]

Comment: I've never seen a "can opener" that looks like that. What if all you have is [a modern can opener?](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7b/Kitchen-Modern-Can-Opener.jpg)

Comment: The image you included has a "hook" at the bottom left. That might work to pry open the can as well, though it's pretty pointy so it might not work well.

Comment: In some areas of the world, the photo shows a can piercer (pointy-end) and a bottle-opener (the blunt end) combination tool. There are also single-purpose tools for either function.

Comment: Question: Is using a tool that is designed and named for the task to be accomplished a "life" or any other kind of "hack?" Paraphrase: Is using an opener to open something properly as designed, a hack, per se?

Comment: @Stan Really good question! It seems to me that easy-open cans (like soda cans) negate the use for a can opener. People never associate easy-open cans with can openers. Can openers are for cans that are not "easy-open". (I just thought of paper glue, and how you wouldn't ever think of needing that for an enveloped with adhesive you can lick. But if your lickable adhesive fails for some reason, you COULD use glue or tape to seal the envelope.)

Answer (score 10):

Get a metal spoon or butter knife and you can lay the edge of the handle across the opening, similar to the way the tab sits, and apply pressure opening the can.

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly advise against using sharp objects (like screwdrivers) to make a hole that is different in shape from the intended opening. It could result in small bits of aluminium (that the can is made of) falling into the contents, and possibly cause harm if ingested.

Just simulate the usual way of opening cans using a spoon handle or a similar non-sharp object in the same motion as the original tab.

Comment: Yeah, scaremongering is not needed unless you are working for the beverage company.  Urban legend has it that the non-detaching ring pull was replaced by the lift tab because scores of Americans would wind up in hospital ER every year from having opened can and dropped pull tab in can and then drunk tab.  I cannot believe drunk Americans to be this careless. I believe tabs were changed to reduce litter and increase recycle amount by a few %. Unlikely that a harmful piece of metal will be accidentally dislodged with any type of tool, cutting your hand is possible with knife blade

Answer (score 3):

Lay a teaspoon on the hole, face-down, keeping the tip of the head against the edge of the tab/hole.

Apply pressure to the middle of the head of the spoon.

This will push the tab into the hole, in much the same fashion as the actual ring pull would.

Take care to only press on the middle of the head of the spoon - stay away from the edges, otherwise your finger may slip into the hole when the tab gives way (which nobody wants).

Answer (score 1):

OK, you all have no clue about how to do this. 
Get a blunt plastic object, like the base of lighter (I can guarantee that that will work) and then place it against the outside edge of the scored tab (bit that pops down) and then rub back and forth while applying medium  pressure. The tab will burst open (be warned, it makes one hell of a bang). The drink remains carbonated and won't fizz over.

Comment: https://youtu.be/CbJFokRLjqM

Comment: Honestly a whole damn lot cooler than any other way

Comment: WARNING: the YouTube account has been nuked, which hints this might be just a hoax. I advise against trying the suggested method here.

Comment: @PipWherrett your link is broken.
Here is a link that works. not English, but you don't need it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DvA6SChvO8

Answer (score 1):

A mechanical can opener with the spinning gears or an electric one can be gently used to cut off the *entire* top of the can. Then just be sure to pour into a glass as you will cut your mouth on the shredded can.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to open it with no tools: use your nails to pierce the white bit which has the barcode or bit that says not to be sold separately. It will explode though, so make a large hole.

Answer (score 0):

**Solutions:**

- Take a pair of pliers or like tool and  grab what is left if the tab. With these pull upwards and open the can. It make a few trys and ruin the can, so drink the soda out of a cup to avoid messing with your mouth.

---

[image]

P-38 can opener.

*All pictures taken from Wikipedia.org. Shown to demonstrate types of can openers available to use.*

- Use a can opener. You can avoid all of the situation by just opening the can with a can opener. There are [portable can openers](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-38_can_opener)(p-38 can opener is a really small one) so you are always ready.

**Some forceful methods:**

- Use a sharp object, I.e. a screwdriver or other clean sharp object to poke a hole in the can. Be very careful, and direct the object away from your body. Make sure the object is clean.
- Take a sturdy blunt object and place it on the tab. Then apply force, the tab should fall in making the contents accessible.

Some other helpful advice can be found on [this site](http://gnobal.net/114/internet-search-challenge-how-to-open-a-soda-can-if-the-push-pull-tab-broke-off).

Answer (score 0):

Using force is always an option. :)

Seriously, though, the main thing you want to avoid is squeezing the can while you are opening it, or you *will* have a mess.  Aim for the perforations with a screwdriver or a spoon and you should be able to ease it open.

Answer (score 0):

Pushing in the indented area with a flathead screwdriver worked best for me!

Comment: Could you provide instructions on how to apply the screwdriver to open the beverage?